# Console Application Args to Task Scheduler Parameters (CLOSED)

Tags: c#, arguments, scheduled-tasks

I've done a lot of research on this subject and all I found were misleading sites about information I wasn't looking for. So I hope anyone here can give me a solid explanation.

Basicly, I have a program, which I want to use in Task Scheduler. But whatever parameter I give in the box to put them in, it keeps saying The index is located outside of the array bounds.

I understand that parameters are linked to the args? So can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string paramList = string.Join("", args);
   string[] parameter = paramList.Split(',');

   string ScanPath = parameter[0]; //Which directory to scan
   string MailToAddress = parameter[1]; //Which e-mail to send the log to
   string ScanHours = parameter[2]; //How many hours to scan
}
```

I found this somewhere on codeproject. I assumed that the first arg is linked to the first parameter, etc, etc.

In Task Scheduler I basicly browse to the released executable:
[image]

Of course the `path` and `mail` part is much longer when running the program, but this is just for example.

Do I need to remove the commas? And/or add `-` in front of every parameter? Or is it something completely else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually command line arguments are split by a single space character, not comma's. Furthermore, if any of your arguments *contain* spaces, you need to wrap the argument in double quotes:

```
"C:\My Documents\xxx" x@y.z 10
```

I don't know how the task scheduler supplies its parameters, but you could of course log the arguments before using them, to see exactly what's passed to your application.

Comment: It's not wrong, but you'd usually check `args.Length` beforehand, instead of just assuming the user has provided the right amount of arguments. I hope the logging will show exactly what's going on.

Comment: There is in fact something wrong with the array according to my program? Because the error starts at `[1]`, and when I try to switch `[1]` with `[0]`, the error stays at `[1]`. So that means the error starts at the second line, that it can't go further.

Comment: I've edited the code a little bit (some of the data that's not visible in the question) and now it's working like a charm :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though i think you know this allready, just to be sure:
You need to seperate parameters by blanks. Also if parameters contains blanks (path for example) put them in doublequotes.

Why dont you write a simple test-app that dumps the complete paramsarray into a textfile.
Then you should know how to interprete correctly.

Comment: Haha sorry I didn't knew that. I'm just a beginner, don't judge me ;) Can I ask you for any ideas on where to put the doublequotes?

Comment: text.exe "C:\Programfiles x86\Whatever" nextparamnoblanks "param with blanks!"